# Ideal of a ring of matrices

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $F$ be a (commutative) field.

$R$, the matrices of the form
$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b \\
0 & c \\
 \end{array} \right)$ with $a,b,c \in F$, is a subring of the ring $M_2(F)$ of 2 x 2 matrices with entries in $F$.

Give a non-trivial two-sided ideal $I$ of $R$.

I read a lot on ideals (course notes and online), but I have a hard time understanding the concept of ideals... Especially in this example with matrices. How would one define the ideal of $R$ in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to construct ideals is to look at the singly generated ideals. These are of the form $RxR$ for some fixed element $x$. Of course you run the risk that $RxR=R$ and then the ideal is trivial.

But if we try a couple examples we can make them work:

First, try $x=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. We have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}d&e\\0&f\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&ae\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So the set
$$
I=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\0&0\end{bmatrix}:\ a\in F\right\}
$$
is a proper two-sided ideal. Or if you try $y=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}d&e\\0&f\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}ad&ae\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Thus
$$
J=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix}:\ a,b\in F\right\}
$$
is another proper two-sided ideal.